# D - send data to socket

Tags: sockets, d, send

I have the following primitive server in D:

```
import std.stdio; 
import std.socket; 

int main() {

const int port = 8080; 

InternetAddress addr = new InternetAddress(InternetAddress.ADDR_ANY, port); 
TcpSocket server = new TcpSocket(AddressFamily.INET); 

server.bind(addr); 
server.listen(10);


for(;;) {

    Socket newclient = server.accept(); 

    newclient.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"); 
    newclient.send("Content-type: text/html\n\n"); 
    newclient.send("Hi from D!");

    newclient.shutdown(SocketShutdown.BOTH); 
    newclient.close(); 
}



    return 0;
}
```

If I connect with a browser, it doesn't display a "Hi From D!", but simply disconnects.

My assumption is that send() buffers the data and I have to flush that buffer. But I haven't figured out how you would do that. Interestingly enough, the code works if write some data to STDOUT with writefln("asdf asdf\n"); after the last call of send(), hence my assumption.

Or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: Use `\r\n` when dealing with the HTTP because if I remember well, that is what protocol requires. Anyway, what I wonder is - are you 100% sure it is not some Windows firewall problem? barti_ddu's code should work on Windows as well, and the only reason why it does not that makes sense is the Windows firewall not allowing you to connect...

Answer (score 5):

Your code actually worked for me.... but a few changes that might help anyway:

1) add a Content-length header to the response

2) use \r\n\r\n to end the headers rather than \n\n.

If those don't help, it could also be a problem with a firewall or similar blocking your connection.

Comment: Yeah. While the header's first line means that it's claiming to be HTTP 1.1, it's definitely not valid HTTP 1.1, much as it might work if the receiver is lax enough.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed the header but it still doesn't work for me. I'm testing on Windows. If I "port" this code to perl for instance, it works just fine. Hm.

Comment: I don't have a Windows box available right now so still guessing, but what I'd do next is write a simple client program that connects and dumps the network output to the screen. Then is nothing comes out, look back at buffer, and if you get something, go back to the protocol (perhaps another problem is you aren't receiving data, so the browser sees the response as something it never asked for.)

Being in a buffer is a possibility, but I doubt it because closing the socket *should* flush any pending output.

Answer (score 5):

This may rather be a header problem, try something like:

```
// -- cut --

Socket newclient = server.accept(); 

newclient.send("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"); 
newclient.send("Content-type: text/plain\r\n"); 
newclient.send("Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
newclient.send("Hi from D!\r\n");

newclient.shutdown(SocketShutdown.BOTH); 
newclient.close();

// -- cut --
```

**Update:** I have re-checked the snippet under *win64* and my guess about ***content-type*** seems right. You should either provide valid html if you declare content as ***text/html***, i.e.

```
<html><body>Hi from D!</body></html>
```

or provide correct contnet type (i.e. ***text/plain***).

Note, that i get this kind of behaviour only on windows with ie, on linux your snippet works as is (with ff, telnet, etc.).